# first occurrence of age in a nuggets eating contest

Tags: r

I just have one simple question,
what is the fastest way to get a first occurrence of age for each person in a data frame? (in essence we need to extract unique values of each person based on the first time they participated)

```
Person    Age   Result
soso      22    199
bobo      18    208
soso      23    207
folo      25    197
bobo      19    226
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `aggregate` together with `min`.

Comment: By first occurrence of age, you mean the youngest age that a person participated, _i.e._ their minimum age?

Comment: yes, that what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to get the fastest extraction using either `unique` with `by` option

```
unique(df2, by = "Person")
```

Or extracting with row index

```
setDT(df2)[df2[, .I[1L],Person]$V1]
```

#### Update

If we need the minimum 'Age' row per 'Person

```
setDT(df2)[, .SD[which.min(Age)], Person]
```

---

Or if we prefer `dplyr`, then

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   group_by(Person) %>%
   slice(1L)
```

#### Update

```
df2 %>%
    group_by(Person) %>%
    filter(Age == min(Age))
```

---

Or without using any external library

```
df2[with(df2, Age==ave(Age, Person, FUN = min)),]
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract the ages as a list after that? or is there a straight function to use instead of the libraries? Your answer is very informative by the way, thanks.

Comment: @Roryme Yes, it is possible, but based on your comment, you want the minimum 'age' per person or is it the first row?  Very confusing

Comment: I actually gave you an upvote. and I just chose your answer.

Comment: I think people are just not liking the whole nuggets eating contest, so they have been down voting everything like crazy :(. Like I'm really going to use those functions on a real nuggets eating contest.

Comment: @Roryme  I think people don't want the wrong person win the nugget eating contest as your description was sketchy

Comment: Nugget eaters are people too!